# Site collection upgraded to 2013 - help me identify what's missing

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, infopath, upgrade

This is the first time I have dealt with SP2013 running in 2010 mode, so there may be some things that are fairly common knowledge that I do not know about.

I have been brought in to help troubleshoot some problems with workflows on a site that was upgraded to 2013 using the DB attach method.  The site is still running in 2010 mode.  I was not personally involved with the migration/upgrade, but based on the errors I am seeing, my gut tells me that not everything made it over from the 2010 farm.  And [this article](http://blog.appliedis.com/2012/11/13/sharepoint-conference-2012-upgrade-to-sharepoint-2013-with-less-migration-migraines/) says, regarding upgraded sites still running in 2010 mode:

> However, the site continues to function as it did on the old farm,
>   provided the required customizations were installed prior to the
>   database attach.

which leads me to believe that some customization or something was not installed properly prior to the DB attach.

**The Symptoms**

- New 2010 workflows created through SPD on the migrated site can be saved but not published.  They fail with the error:

  > SharePoint Designer encountered an error generating the task form.
- Previously existing workflows can be re-published, but when started, they fail with an unexpected error.  Looking into the ULS logs reveals that the specific error is:

  > System.Web.HttpException: The file '/_layouts/IniWrkflIP.aspx' does
  >   not exist.

A search of the file system on the server (this is on-prem) confirms that the file is in fact missing.

- Looking at the site content types shows three content types in the "Custom Content Types" group: "Approval," "Feedback," and "Task_x0028_2_x0029_".  Each of these content types show an unresolved resource string as the name of the parent content type:

  > $Resources:_FeatureIdc9c9515d-e4e2-4001-9050-74f980f93160,WorkflowTaskIP_Name;

I looked up that feature ID from the resource string token, and it is listed as

> Microsoft Office Server workflows (OffWFCommon)

My first instinct after that was to go to the site collection features and make sure that the feature was enabled, but to my surprise, **it isn't even listed as an available feature.**

In fact, there are a slew of SP OOB default features that I was expecting to see, which are not there.  The only thing I can assume is that this is due to the fact that the site is running in 2010 mode.

But, based on these symptoms, can anyone help me identify what feature / customization / etc. is missing from this new environment, and what can I do to activate / install it?

Does it have to do with InfoPath? Both the missing file and the unresolved resource string token have a conspicuous "IP" in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this up --

Turns out the problem was indeed related to InfoPath, specifically the lack of InfoPath Services on the 2013 farm.

The old 2010 farm was running SP 2010 Enterprise, and the farm the site was migrated to is running SP 2013 Foundation.  So... no InfoPath Services available.  Oops.